# Trying to determine equation for this second-order transient circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have been trying to determine the second order differential equation for the attached circuit, but I don't seem to be able to get the answer my professor provides. I need to get a differential equation relating the current \$i_2\$ with the current \$i_s\$, but I have not managed to do so. The answer provided by my professor is:
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{L_{1} L_{2}}{R_{x}} i_{2}^{\prime \prime}+\left(L_{1}+\frac{R+R_{x}}{R_{x}} L_{2}\right) i_{2}^{\prime}+R i_{2}=L_{1} i_{S}^{\prime}
\end{equation}$$

During my attempt, I assumed that no current flows through the resistor Rx, since the current can always take the path through the inductor, which has no resistance. I know this may seem basic for most of you: this is indeed an basic course for physics students. If anyone could help me understand how to tackle the problem, it will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You are writing a differential equation describing the *dynamics* of the circuit, not the DC behavior, so your assumption is wrong. Write down the equations describing the I-V relations of each component, then do some derivatives and combine it into a single equation.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. I still don't get to the right answer. There are certain voltages I am not able to simplify. I you could give me more concrete advice, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Well inductors are non-linear devices; at \$t=0\$ will they appear different?

Comment: Show us your work. We are not here to do your homework for you. You must show that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: @coffee_pls I'm confused. Is \$i_s\$ suggesting a function of \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$? Or is **s** just a name and \$i_s\$ a function of time? I see derivatives in your equation so I think time. But then I see **s** and the desire to form a ratio of \$i_2\$ to \$i_s\$ and I wonder if that's true, anymore. This may just be me, though, not reading well with understanding. I'd appreciate a kick to the head, in that case.

Comment: I think \$i_s\$ is just a function of time, **s** being just a name.

Comment: @jonk The s is \$i_s\$ is almost certainly stands for "source".

Comment: @Carl Yes. I also thought it very likely. But I'd prefer not to assume when I can just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The inductors can only be considered as shorts during **dc**. However, you are looking for a differential equation for the circuit and are thus searching for the **transient response**.

In that case, you have to use the general formula for the inductor voltage \$V_L=L \frac{\text{d}I_L}{\text{d}t}\$.

Note that it doesn't make sense to talk about **one** differential equation for this circuit. If you wanted to find the transient response of the voltage across \$R_x\$ that would needs its own differential equation. In this case it looks like you are asked to find the transient response of the current through \$L_2\$ called \$i_2 \$ - so you will need a differential equation specifically for that.

An obivous choice of analysis tool would be mesh-currents. Do you know how write those up?

Comment: Inductors can only be considered as shorts **at dc** not for a steady-state ac analysis.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You are right.